# Proper Use : @import in LESS to bring dependant files together

Tags: import, compilation, less

I am trying to do some work with .LESS, and am running into a conflict with a fellow programmer, and attempting to discern the best use here.

Essentially, the debate is over the proper use of @import to bring .less files together that cannot compile on their own. For instance, assume the following..

## variables.less

```
// some variables are defined here
```

## reset.less

```
// variables are used here
```

## compile.less

```
@import("variables.less")
@import("reset.less")
```

Now then, if you tried to compile `reset.less`, it would fail. Because it requires things from `variables.less`. To one of us, this is perfectly fine because it allows us to modularize our project into pieces. But the other disagrees, because they claim each file should stand alone.

What do some of you more experienced `.less` coders think on this matter? What is "Accepted" practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously, what is "best practice" for one company may not be so for another. However, it is a very common practice to have them split as you note. [Bootstrap](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/tree/master/less) does this.

If it is necessary to be able to compile each individually, but also a desire to modularize, then what you could do is keep it as you note above, but also define within each submodule (like `reset.less`) an

```
@import-once "variables.less"
```

at the beginning. That way, if one is just compiling `reset.less` it works, but in `compile.less` it will only do the initial `import` of the `variables.less` file and not any subsequent calls from the submodules.

Comment: What if `import-once` is called on the same file in multiple different files?

Comment: @Ciel: It _should not_ import it multiple times. You can double check that easy enough by creating a simple class in a file, `.myClass { color: red;}` and then set that to `import-once` in a couple of files (like `variables.less` and `reset.less`), and then go look at `compile.less` to see if it shows up two times or just once (it should be just once, whichever file is loaded first).